# VLOOKUP returning the wrong value in a range

Tags: google-sheets

I've got the following table:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 29/06/2020 | €0.8891400 |
| 30/06/2020 | €0.8902000 |
| 01/07/2020 | €0.8887000 |
| 02/07/2020 | €0.8898800 |
| 03/07/2020 | €0.8891000 |
| 04/07/2020 | €0.8892843 |
| 05/07/2020 | €0.8891400 |
| 06/07/2020 | €0.8839750 |
| 07/07/2020 | €0.8869300 |

I want to find a value in the **Value** column based on a specific date. I've tried using a `VLOOKUP` formula like so, where A2 is `04/07/2020`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, B2:C, 2 FALSE)
```

But it is returning the value relative to the date before the one I'm looking for. It is returning `€0.8891000`, which is the value relative to `03/07/2020`, not `04/07/2020`.

Any help understanding why this is happening?

Comment: Your formula works fine on my end. Have you checked if formatting on the range is correct? also it would be great if you can share a dummy sheet where this the issue is reproducible so we can help you better.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you specified the range of your table so we can relate it to your formula. Also, your formula is incorrect: It's missing a "," between "2" and "FALSE".

Answer (score 0):

You use `VLOOKUP` not correctly
Use this

```
=VLOOKUP(A30, A32:C, 3, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Had a similar issue. What solved for me was the fourth parameter: not sorting the results (setting it to false, as in the example by @Swen).